# How make daily data transfer from AWS s3 to GCP GCS?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, data-transfer

I have a client who wants their data to be transferred daily to GCP bucket from their S3 to Google Cloud Storage bucket. Is there any way to create schedule transfer or recurring transfer from s3 to GCS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the service called **Storage Transfer** service: https://console.cloud.google.com/transfer

you can create a pipeline and schedule it as per requirement and run to clone all data from AWS S3 to GCP.

here main service URL: https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer-service

You can use `storage transfer service` to the transfer bucket data

- AWS S3 to GCP
- Azure to GCP
- GCP to GCP

it also supports the TSV file.

You can configure this service to run at a specific time daily.

Comment: I think "vice versa" is not true. It's one way i.e. you cannot transfer data from GCS to an external storage.

Comment: vice versa is not true its only import from other sources to gcp.